# Java API to do graphing

Tags: java, excel, api, plot

Does anyone know a decent Java API that could be used to plot data? (I'd say it should be 'almost' as good as Excel)

If not, any way to integrate a Java program into Excel? 
Currently, I have to write the output of my java program to text files, then write a macro to load the data into the Excel spread sheets and do the plotting there.

Thanks much!

Comment: what type of charts do you need? and how much control youd like to have? much control you can gain by using https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse If you want to have fast results, i'll stick with excel if i were you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). It's pretty good, open source and pretty actively devoloped. It can also be integrated with other tools such as [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/) (if you want to output HTML and/or PDF files).

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty decent. (Don't want to mark this as 'answer' right now, since I'd like to have different options. :) )

Answer (score 1):

[***jXLS***](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/index.html)

It supports:

1. Complex object graph export
2. Dynamic grouping of data
3. Charts, Macros and many other Excel features in XLS template

and many more...

Example at [*Basic Chart Sample*](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/chartsample.html)